# Limit scrollable area within WKWebView content

Tags: ios, wkwebview

## Update:

I ran further experiments and as it turns out, I was mistaken about the solution working for `UIWebView`.  I had tested it, but didn't look close enough I guess.  After pondering matt's comments and re-reading the "solution" I found/mentioned, I noticed they weren't talking about webviews.  I've since hacked up a solution which embeds the my `UIWebView` inside of a `UIScrollView` of my own.  Then I "disable" the `UIWebView`'s scrollview by setting it's content size and frame to the size of the entire HTML document.  This approach should work for either `UIWebView` or `WKWebView`.  Once I clean up the solution, I'll come back and update.

## Original:

I'm developing an iOS app that has a `WKWebView` for reading HTML content.  **At times I need need to be able to restrict scrolling within a certain portion of the web content.**  eg say the web content is 10,000 points vertically and I want to limit scrolling between 5,000 and 8,000.  I always show the full width.

<s>I found this solution **for `UIWebView`**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3973649</s>

The solution suggests setting the `webview.scrollView.contentSize` like:

```
CGSize desiredContentSize = CGSizeMake(self.webView.scrollView.contentSize.width,
                                       8000-5000);
self.webView.scrollView.contentSize = desiredContentSize;
```

and adjusting the `webview.scrollView.frame`'s origin to -5000;

```
CGRect scrollFrame;
scrollFrame.origin = CGPointMake(0, -5000);
scrollFrame.size = self.webView.frame.size;
self.webView.scrollView.frame = scrollFrame;
```

**I have found this works well with `UIWebView`, but it does not work with `WKWebView`.**  With `WKWebView`, I am noticing that the scrollView's contentSize gets automatically reset to fit the content each time the user scrolls or when JavaScript updates the content.  This did not happen with `UIWebView`.

I found I could "force" my desired contentSize to "stick" with this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8214325/3352624

Unfortunately, this causes jitters when I hit the top and bottom of the viewable area.  Using this KVO approach is how I noticed `WKWebView` keeps resetting it's contentSize so frequently.

**How can I restrict `WKWebView`'s scrollable area?  Is there a good way to prevent the contentSize from being changed?**

For what it's worth, in this case, the HTML content is controlled content from an internal API.  The only javascript run is my own.  I am targeting iOS 8 and 9.

Comment: Since it's your content and your JavaScript, why don't you do this the right way and just blank out the part of the content you don't want the user to see?

Comment: @matt Good point.  The boundaries I am placing surround suggested daily readings.  I have another requirement to allow the user to pass these boundaries with an extended pull gesture.  The material beyond the boundary needs to be visible during this gesture.  If they pull far enough I move the boundaries to the next section.  Secondly, I'm using the rangy javascript library for highlighting and I'm pretty sure it would mess up serialization.

Comment: Good answer. But my point remains: you will be a much happier camper if you implement this feature using css-and-javascript and don't try to subvert the web view itself. It's just a view, and it isn't set up for the kind of thing you're trying to make it do.

Comment: @matt From my research I was coming at it as ["it's just a UIScrollView"](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/04/understanding-uiscrollview/).  I originally intended to hide the content with css-and-javascript, until I saw the requirement for the peeking-extended-pull-to-next-section requirement.  I'm new-ish to JavasScript.  Do you think it is feasible to accomplish such a requirement in JavaScript & css?  It looks easy with UIWebView.

Comment: If it were just a scroll view I would know how to limit scrolling. I'd have a delegate on the scroll view so I can see what the user is doing, and if the user scrolls to my limit, I'd shift the content offset back so the user can't go any further (or even turn scrolling off entirely by disabling the pan gesture recognizer). But I don't know if you can do with a web view, because it isn't your scroll view.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to limit the scrollable area in your wkwebview is not a good idea try to change the content inset or frame(worst) of the web view, and well... javascript injection solutions might not work.

It because the secret of the smoothly scroll of a web view is that it loads the full body, this let you explore this full body through the native scroll view included like subview in the web view, letting you see a full body fraction which is proportional to the web view size (it works better than use, for example, of an injection of a container who sets the overflow style in "scroll").

Based in the last explanation and in your example:

"I'm developing an iOS app that has a WKWebView for reading HTML content. At times I need need to be able to restrict scrolling within a certain portion of the web content. eg say the web content is 10,000 points vertically and I want to limit scrolling between 5,000 and 8,000. I always show the full width."

The solution will be:

```
CGFloat topScrollLimit = 5000, bottomScrollLimit = 8000;
CGFloat contentHeight = myWebView.scrollView.contentSize.height; //10000
myWebView.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(topScrollLimit*-1.0f, 0, (contentHeight-bottomScrollLimit)*-1.0f, 0);
```

In addition if you want to prevent the scroll gesture exceed the edge of the limit you can add the line:

```
myWebView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
```

For other examples with a range minor or content minor than the web view height probably you must reduce the web view heigh.